# Best method to clear large sections of land to bedrock

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Using TNT, I am trying to roughly mine a 360x360 area of land completely to bedrock. Does anyone know the most efficient way to blast massive sections of land relatively cleanly?

Comment: Just to confirm, vanilla survival right?

Comment: No, on creative, but on the xbox 360. So no console commands like PC.

Comment: Hmm, is it land or sea?

Comment: It WAS sea, but I already spent around 100 hours getting rid of the water, lol.

Comment: Create a bedrock border around it and blow up everything inside?

Comment: Yeah, that's the general idea, but how should I grid it out? 2 blocks between each stack of TNT to bedrock? 3 block between? Is it better to go vertical or horizontal? Should there be single stacks of TNT, or in a 3x3 configuration? 5x5? Is a grid pattern even the best way to go?

Comment: I would do 3 blocks between. 3x3 and grid yes.

Comment: I gave the 3x3 a shot in a relatively small area, and there was a decent amount of crap throughout the hole it made that didn't get destroyed. The time it takes to clean the crap up doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: TNT won't be perfect, there's always going to be crap to clean up. Go the Achievement Hunter route, get a bunch of friends, give em all beer, and spend the night digging

Answer (score 1):

I would keep placing TNT blocks every 7 blocks or so in a grid formation, lighting them up, watching the fireworks, then placing TNT blocks again in the same locations.

- The deeper you can get them, the better. TNT has a random spherical blast radius.
- You could also randomly place blocks and I suppose it would save time. You could go deep and create a huge cluster of TNT underground, then blow it up.

Of course you get get a bunch of friends and clear the area manually (Or even do it yourself.) Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult, because water and lava source blocks are unaffected by TNT, so any underground veins would become a problem unless you're willing to put in the time commitment to go around with a bucket and collect each and every single source block.  I wouldn't be surprised if you are (I would be), so really, just place TNT on the land you want to clear and blow it up.  Simple as that.  Also, try to be systematic about it.  I know from experience that systematic work gets the best results (both in Minecraft and in life!).

Comment: You can also fill-in lava and water by just placing blocks inside the lakes, and dig them back out afterward. (I'd do this for water but not for lava, as lava is a finite resource)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

Make a tower out of blocks (I would say 10 high but the height is not crucial).

[image: Tower]

Place a dispenser facing down on top of the tower.

[image: Dispenser]

Load the dispenser up with TNT

[image: loading the dispenser]

Make this redstone circuit:

[image: redstone circuit]

Then complete the circuit!

[image: Completing the circuit]